# COMBINE TWO QUERY IN SQL

Tags: sql

I want to combine this two query

table 1:

```
Select fldCode,(COALESCE(sum(distinct fldIN),0)) -  (COALESCE(sum(distinct fldOut),0)) as totalStock from tblInventory group by fldCode
```

| fldCode | totalStock |
| --- | --- |
| Humiseal | 88 |
| Silicon Rubber | 54 |

table 2:

```
Select fldCode, fldSafetyStock from tblItems
```

| fldCode | fldSafetyStock |
| --- | --- |
| Humiseal | 165 |
| Silicon Rubber | 105 |

with the result like this table

RESULT TABLE:

| fldCode | fldSafetyStock | totalStock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Humiseal | 165 | 88 |
| Silicon Rubber | 105 | 54 |

Comment: You want a JOIN.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with VB.NET. Please don't trick people into viewing irrelevant questions by applying irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.fldCode,A.totalStock,ITM.fldSafetyStock  FROM
(
   Select fldCode,
    (COALESCE(sum(distinct fldIN),0)) - (COALESCE(sum(distinct  fldOut),0)) as totalStock 
     from tblInventory group by fldCode
)AS A
JOIN tblItems AS ITM ON A.fldCode=ITM.fldCode
```

Could you please try this

Comment: it's working thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we can rely on both tables having all/the same items to report, we can use a join here:

```sql
SELECT t1.fldCode, t1.fldSafetyStock, COALESCE(t2.total, 0) AS totalStock
FROM tblItems t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT fldCode, SUM(DISTINCT fldIN) - SUM(DISTINCT fldOut) AS total
    FROM tblInventory
    GROUP BY fldCode
) t2
    ON t2.fldCode = t1.fldCode;
```

The above answer assumes that every `fldCode` which you want to report can be found in the `tblItems` table.  Items may be out of inventory, and the report would just list zero for the total stock in that case.

Comment: it's working. thank you